# GDAL external overviews not recognized by ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal

I am adding external overviews to a number of TIF files with GDAL as follows:

```
gdaladdo -ro file.tif 2 4 8 16 --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW LZW
```

Then, when I add the tif file to ArcGis is still asking me if I want to build pyramids. It seems that the .ovr file is not fully recognized. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that ArcGIS when creates the pyramids on a raster added in a data frame, by default sets 8 levels of pyramids. If in gdal I add 8 levels, then ArcGIS it doesn't ask me again if I want to create the pyramids. So the GDAL command is:

```
gdaladdo -ro file.tif 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW LZW
```